# Box2D body swipe

Tags: ios, cocos2d-iphone, box2d

Can we detect a swipe gesture for box2d body? 
For example:

- Detect wwipe left gesture body.y-10
- Detect swipe right gesture body.x+10
- etc...

Any ideas?

Comment: Box2D is a phys engine. It does nothing with touches and GUI.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have a look at `UISwipeGestureRecognizer`.  Add one to the OpenGL view and whenever it fires do something to your Box2D objects.  The recognizer will provide you with the starting position of the swipe.

Answer (score 0):

For whichever layer you have your box2d world in you can make the layer a  when you implement the method (BOOL)ccTouchBegan.. you can record the position of the initial touch. in the (void)ccTouchMoved, you can begin to track the distance that the touch has moved. If the distance is long enough for a swipe then you then process the information and translate it to movement in Box2d by using ->ApplyForce(), ->SetTransform() methods on a b2Body